# How dangerous is a compact anti-pattern, DetachedCriteria based, DAO utilitary for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, utilities, detachedcriteria

Long time ago I created an one-class-hibernate-util to ease my life on **really really small applications** using DetachedCriteria, as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;

/* WARNING: This utility was projected only for applications of one operation per use per mapping!
Using it for multiple operations characterizes the anti-pattern "session-per-operation". */
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final int SEARCH = 0;
    private static final int LIST = 1;
    private static final int SAVE = 2;
    private static final int UPDATE = 3;
    private static final int SAVE_OR_UPDATE = 4;
    private static final int DELETE = 5;
    private static final int MERGE = 6;
    private static SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY;

    // Single session factory instantiation
    static {SESSION_FACTORY = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();}

    // Opens the session and executes only one operation on the transaction
    private static Object executeTransaction(Object object, int operation) {
        Object output = null;
        Session session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            switch (operation) {
                case SEARCH: output = ((DetachedCriteria) object).getExecutableCriteria(session).uniqueResult(); break;
                case LIST: output = ((DetachedCriteria) object).getExecutableCriteria(session).list(); break;
                case SAVE: session.save(object); break;
                case UPDATE: session.update(object); break;
                case SAVE_OR_UPDATE: session.saveOrUpdate(object); break;
                case DELETE: session.delete(object); break;
                case MERGE: session.merge(object); break;
                default: throw new HibernateException("No operation was executed on the database.");
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return output;
    }

    // Usable methods, named accordingly to the operation:
    public static Object searchCriteria(DetachedCriteria criteria) {return executeTransaction(criteria, SEARCH);}
    public static List<?> listCriteria(DetachedCriteria criteria) {return (List<?>) executeTransaction(criteria, LIST);}
    public static void save(Object object) {executeTransaction(object, SAVE);}
    public static void update(Object object) {executeTransaction(object, UPDATE);}
    public static void saveOrUpdate(Object object) {executeTransaction(object, SAVE_OR_UPDATE);}
    public static void delete(Object object) {executeTransaction(object, DELETE);}
    public static void merge(Object object) {executeTransaction(object, MERGE);}
}
```

This allows me to interact with the database by calling `HibernateUtil.searchCriteria()/listCriteria()/save()/update()/saveOrUpdate()/delete()/merge()`, but I actually use it on very rare situations (tiny applications) due to its *session-per-operation* nature.

The problem is, I just found out that my fellow co-workers've been using it in bigger applications, running over the use of proper DAO patterns. My fault. I'm worried about possible side-effects, like an overhead or overload, but I don't know exactly what problems I should worry about. Is this risky enough for me to start remaking the DAO in their applications?

Can some of you more experienced programmer or DBA guys share me some light, here? I'd appreciate very much.

**EDIT**

Changed it to close the session. What I do now to avoid lazy initialization errors is to set `lazy="false"` in every many-to-one mappings in hbm.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem you should worry about is transactional integrity. I would bet that you'll find many use-cases where several safe/update/saveOrUpdate/delete operations should be in a single transaction, but are each done in their own transaction "thanks to" this helper class.

The other problem is that using this helper class forces the use of two session factories instead of just one, since this helper class uses its own, private, session factory.

I would remove this class, and use Spring or EJBs to have declarative transaction management, and use the session per transaction pattern, or the open session in view pattern, which both make sure the session is closed at some time.